# Writing numpy.random.get_state() to file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, numpy, tuples

`numpy.random.get_state()` returns a `tuple`. I want to write this to a file so I can use the same state later if required.

I got it down to the following, but `csv` throws an error:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def write_state():
    with open("state_file", "w") as file:
        csv.register_dialect("custom", delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
        writer = csv.writer(file, dialect="custom")
        for val in np.random.get_state():
            writer.writerow(val)
```

Traceback:

```
  File "MCVE.py", line 21, in <module>
    write_state()
  File "MCVE.py", line 11, in write_state
    writer.writerow(val)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

What's the appropriate method for writing `np.random.get_state()` to a file so `np.random.set_state()` can use the stored information later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python built-in `cPickle.dump/load` can efficiently write and read many objects such as tuples.

### Writing

```
from cPickle import dump
import numpy as np

with open('state.obj', 'wb') as f:
    dump(np.random.get_state(), f)
```

### Reading

```
from cPickle import load
import numpy as np

with open('state.obj', 'rb') as f:
    np.random.set_state(load(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the line

```
writer.writerow(val)
```

with this

```
writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: Allright, that writes. What would be the inverse of this to read it back into `np.random.set_state()`? There's no point in writing to whatever format if I can't load it correctly afterwards.